# Understanding the difference between .body and body

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am not sure if I understood it correctly. When styling in CSS like this:

```
body {
}
```

I'm referring to an element that belongs to HTML. When I write something like this:

```
.body {
}
```

I'm referring to a class name given by me. Is this correct?

Comment: . is body, # is ID and lacking all that is the actual tag.

Comment: Take a look at this. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pGL6/) get it?

Comment: That's a really poor duplicate...

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look at the article on [CSS Selectors from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors), this is [also a pretty healthy introductory article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) on selectors of the type you list, as well as some other important ones.

A non symbol prefixed 'word' denotes an element (`body`), a 'word' prefixed with a period (`.`) denotes a 'class' (`.body`)

Element selectors (called 'type' selectors) only refer to a specific type of element (e.g. `body`), class selectors can be applied to elements of any type, whereas something like id selectors (a hash preceding a 'word') are unique and can only be applied to a single element (i.e. one `id` per element, which must not be used elsewhere)

There are many types and combinations of selectors, to get an idea you may also want to read up on [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> Specificity is the means by which a browser decides which property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and gets to be applied.
>   Specificity is only based on the matching rules which are composed of
>   selectors of different sorts.

Comment: You should add # for IDs as well. I did in an edit but it seems to have been overwritten by your edit.

Comment: @TylerH It just didn't get accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
.body{
}
```

Would be something like this:

```
<p class='body'>This is text with a class of body</p>
```

But can also affect other elements with the class `.body`.

```
body{
}
```

Will affect the `body` element eg:

```
<body></body>
```

You can also use `ID`'s. For example:

```
#body{
}
```

And you use this similar to a class. However only 1 ID of the same name per page.

```
<p id='body'>This is a body tag, but there should only ever be 1 ID per page.</p>
```

Take a look [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) for more information.